# Does TFS support build in custom web sockets?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I would like to create a custom build step (plugin) in TFS that will call an API in my external server. I would like to send the result from my server to TFS and notify that the job is finished (can take about 1-2 hours). and only then I would like to proceed to the next build step.

For doing so I need to send my server a "Callback URL" to send the output to (once it's finished). My question is can I open such a small web socket in TFS (from my tfs plugin)? Does TFS have a framework for that?, Or should I attach a custom webservice process in my plugin that will run this web socket.

This plugin will be a step as part of my build system and will be finished only after I get the answer from my server, And I'll need to present this data in another plugin in the summary build page.

Does TFS support \ have some of those capabilities or should I implement the whole thing by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not supported. You just can invoke TFS API (e.g. [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview)) to do something with TFS (e.g. queue/stop build)

You can run a loop at a constant speed to check the result from your external server, if the result is finished, continue to run.

For example (powershell with PowerShell build step):

```
$inprocess=true
$loopDelayseconds = 300
while($inprocess)
{
   # send request to server and check the result
   # if result is finished, set inprocess to false, else call Start-Sleep.

    Start-Sleep -s $loopDelayseconds
}
```

Node: you need to change build job timeout value if the task takes too long time (Build definition > General > Build job timeout in minutes).

Comment: Thanks.. I thought a can have a better solution then a "Busy Wait" mechanism.

Comment: @AviramFireberger, I don't think so, because you can't pause and resume the build.

Comment: Yeah I know,, I thought I can have something like a "Semaphore wait" or a "manual event reset" things that will be triggered when the web socket got the response. I guess MS didn't thought about this scenario :\

Comment: @AviramFireberger There isn't that feature in TFS.